# How to write function for dynamically created checkbox on selecting checkbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

How to write a function to get the value of a row on selecting check box. I'm creating check box column dynamically using below code

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "X";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
checkColumn.Width = 50;
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
dataGridView5.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

How to write `check column` function to get the selected row value.

Comment: button_click or CheckChanged?

Comment: Sorry Amiram Korach, I have pasted creating check box code. Function on selecting a check box will also help me. I have to write function to get values of selected row and format the value of a cell before sending it to database.

Comment: Assuming winform you can subscribe for the cellvaluechanged event which fires for each cell, so if the current cell is under your checkbox column you can process further.

Comment: `private void dataGridView5_CellValueChanged(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`.
My datagridview name is dataGridView5, so if use the above function will it work.